# What table is used by Stack Exchange to store answers?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I am using the Stack Exchange data set for an academic project.

I am not able to figure out which table is used to store answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both questions and answers are stored in the Posts table. The questions have PostTypeId = 1, the answers have PostTypeId = 2.